# Hibernate using transaction annotation requires a flush after most if not all queries

Tags: hibernate, transactions, hibernate-annotations

So we're using an annotation to specify that a class requires a transaction like this:

```
@TransactionAttribute (TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED)
public class Foo() {
...
}
```

In the bits of code in that class that actually make changes to the database we found that those changes were not visible to other parts of the code in that class, sometimes the very next line. So we managed to get things working by flushing the query and that feels really really strange. I was expecting that the annotation would make the transaction behave correctly but it seems like we're having to do a lot of massaging to get it to work.

I've spent a lot of time searching with Google and what I've found refers to using this annotation in an xml file rather than right in the code. I'm hoping someone can either explain the behavior of the code or can at least point me to a website that actually deals with the @ annotation specifically.

Edits: We're using JBoss and hibernate and here is a quick sample of code that doesn't work

```
System.out.println("before:" + some_obj.getName());
util = (UtilFacade) EJBFactory.lookup(UtilFacadeBean.class);
some_object.setName("changed");
util.persistEntity(some_obj);
util.refreshEntity(some_obj); // reloads the object to get fresh data
System.out.println("after:" + some_obj.getName());
```

The output from this code is like:

```
>>before:start name
>>after:start name
```

but we expected the second one to show >>after:changed

We managed to work around this by adding util.flush(); after the call to util.persistEntity().

The calls to util rely on an EntityManager that utilizes the hibernate API.

If my question is not clear, let me know what more you want to know and I'll take a stab at editing it.

thanks in advance!

Comment: Show the sample of the offending code.

Comment: Could you please provide more details? For instance, are you using JEE? Which container? Can you provide a sample code for the "expected" behavior and the sample code with the workaround?

Comment: Yep, I'll add stuff. Give me a few moments :)

Comment: more information added in. I hope it's enough.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what does `UtilFacade` do, but if `persistEntity()` calls `persist()` or `save()` and `refreshEntity()` calls `refresh()`, then you are getting the correct behaviour, because `refresh()` overwrites any changes made in the persistence context with the values from the database, and changes made in the persistence context are not saved to the database until flush, therefore database contains the old values when `refresh()` is called.

Comment: This is excellent information. I was assuming the refresh entirely backwards.

Answer (score 0):

So in looking further we needed to set the flush mode. We believe from the behavior we saw that it was defaulting to FlushMode.MANUAL, and we needed it to be either AUTO or ALWAYS. My head is spinning but I feel better now :P

Comment: I think you don't need to do anything with flush mode. The default flush mode is `AUTO`, changes are flushed automatically before executing queries and before transaction commit, so you usually don't need to perform `flush()` manually. Also, this should be a comment rather than answer.